# Rails not working with Safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, safari, mongrel

I'm trying to learn some basics of Ruby on Rails and encountered a problem : my Rails project seems to work fine with Firefox but nothing is shown with Safari?

I also tried this with a new project :

```
rails emptytest
cd emptytest
script/server
```

Producing output:

```
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

With Firefox, the Rails default page was shown, with Safari nothing was shown (no error, "Page source" was also empty).

Hmm... While still writing this, I found the thread [Rails 2.3 just serving Firefox](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2062-rails-23-just-serving-firefox) which adviced to upgrade mongrel (the web server); for some reasons Rails 2.3 and old versions of Mongrel would not work well together.

```
sudo gem update mongrel
```

After that, rails pages were shown as supposed with Safari also.

I'll write this down here if somebody ends up in the same situation. (I didn't found anything relevant with tags ruby-on-rails + safari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, upgrading mongrel solved the problem.